# Error Line in console.error

Tags: javascript

I am trying to throw an error to the Javascript console using `console.error()`, and I would like to set the line number so people can see where they went wrong. Is this at all possible?

Thanks in advance,

Awesomeness01

Comment: Um, why are you not using [`throw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use throw isntead console.error:

```
throw "Error Message";
```

`console.error` just prints out a red message to the browser dev tools and `throw` raises an exception in the current code block which will give all properties that an exception has (stack trace, line number, etc).